# Implicit conversion from int to a class type

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I ran across some code that looked like this:

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;
public:
    Cents(int nCents) : m_nCents(nCents)
    {
    }
 };

int main(){
    Cents c = 0; // why is this possible?
}
```

Why is it possible to convert from int to type of class Cents? Also, is the copy constructor called in this case?

Comment: You tagged it: **implicit conversion**.

Comment: I thought implicit conversion was only done on fundamental types (apparently not). So is 0 converted to type Cents and c is initialized using the copy constructor? If so, what happens when 0 is converted to type Cents?

Comment: There is no "copy constructor" in your code, I'm not sure where you're getting that from. There is only a regular old constructor of the non "copy" variety. And because your constructor accepts a single value, it is included in the list of possible implicit conversions from that value to your class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it possible to convert from int to type of class Cents?

It is allowed because it's handy sometimes. But it may also be problematic: that's why you can forbid such implicit constructions by making the class constructor `explicit`.

> Also, is the copy constructor called in this case?

Since it's an rvalue, the call would be to a move constructor/assignment (which could fallback to a copy ctor/assignment); but the compiler will likely omit that. If you wrote that explicitly, it would be equivalent to:

```
Cents c = Cents(0);
```